# Displacing the social sharing buttons

Tags: wordpress, button, plugins, sharing

I use the social sharing plugin AddToAny with wordpress. Right now the sharing buttons are placed directly after the content of the post, before the category flags. I would like to displace the buttons in that way that they are shown after the category flags. But unfortunately I don't have any idea how to do it. I would be very grateful if you can help me in this regard.

Thank you!

Best wishes, Pradhana

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good start - http://fontawesome.io/examples/

Font Awesome has everything you'll need to make your own social buttons

Comment: The buttons are complete. I want to displace the buttons. (Sorry, I didn't mean replace.)